# How add the ProjectExplorer to an Eclipse e4 RCP Application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is it possible to add the ProjectExplorer to an Eclipse e4 RCP application?
If yes how can I do that? Is this possible if I launch my RCP Application as an E4Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use google and find some links contain this topic, eg [one](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t107132.html), [two](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t71394.html) or [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277902/add-package-explorer-in-rcp-application-result-in-loosing-some-icon). 
Try read and understand the idea of eclipse plugin development, what it is [eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Plug-in-architecture/plugin_architecture.html) and how it reuse. One practical tip for You, if You don't know name of plugin use [Eclipse Spy Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/). Click on **Package Explorer** hit ALT+SHIFT+F1 and will see plugin name, class etc.

[image: The plug-in spy screen]

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was accepted. The provided links are either pre-Eclipse 4, or pointless. Plugin Spy is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

i found another pretty nice way to do it
http://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/